# Buildozer Android API doesn't change

Tags: android, kivy, buildozer

I tried to find answer for this problem everywhere, but I wasn't successful. There are some similar problems, but nothing is exactly what I want. I am trying to build android app from python code using buildozer 1.3. App successfully creates, but target API always defaults to Android API 27, no matter what I set in buildozer.spec. Debug console shows correct version, but Google play console still says API is 27 and must be higher. [google play console error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENCVT.png)

I tried fresh WSL install, reinstall buildozer, I tried to delete buildozer.spec to make sure I edit correct file. Nothing works, it still uses API 27, which is not supported by play console.

here are relevant parts of settings:

API-relevant debug output from console:

```
[INFO]:    Will compile for the following archs: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a
[INFO]:    Found Android API target in $ANDROIDAPI: 31
[INFO]:    Available Android APIs are (27, 30, 31)
[INFO]:    Requested API target 31 is available, continuing.
[INFO]:    Found NDK dir in $ANDROIDNDK: /home/tom/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r21d
[INFO]:    Found NDK version 21d
[WARNING]: Maximum recommended NDK version is 19c, but newer versions may work.
[WARNING]: Newer NDKs may not be fully supported by p4a
```

buildozer.spec (shortened due to SO spam policy, everything else default):

```
buildozer.[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Testovací aplikace

# (str) Package name
package.name = testbattapp

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = tom.apps

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, venv, venv-buildozer

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
# Do not prefix with './'
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy, plyer, android

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (string) Presplash animation using Lottie format.
# see https://lottiefiles.com/ for examples and https://airbnb.design/lottie/
# for general documentation.
# Lottie files can be created using various tools, like Adobe After Effect or Synfig.
#android.presplash_lottie = "path/to/lottie/file.json"

# (str) Adaptive icon of the application (used if Android API level is 26+ at runtime)
#icon.adaptive_foreground.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_fg.png
#icon.adaptive_background.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon_bg.png

# (list) Permissions
#android.permissions = INTERNET

# (list) features (adds uses-feature -tags to manifest)
#android.features = android.hardware.usb.host

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 31

# (int) Minimum API your APK / AAB will support.
android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
android.ndk = 21d

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Enable AndroidX support. Enable when 'android.gradle_dependencies'
# contains an 'androidx' package, or any package from Kotlin source.
# android.enable_androidx requires android.api >= 28
#android.enable_androidx = False

# (list) The Android archs to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
# In past, was `android.arch` as we weren't supporting builds for multiple archs at the same time.
android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone experiences same problem, I just completely reinstalled buildozer, set target API to 32, didn't change sdk and ndk settings (left commented), and now it somehow works like a charm! Perhaps new version is available that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a faster way to solve it.

You should uncomment and change following line of buildozer.spec:

```
    # (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
    android.api = 33
```

then build apk using Buildozer:

```
buildozer -v android release
```

BTW:

```
33 means API level 33 = Android 13
31 means API level 31 = Android 12
30 means API level 30 = Android 11
```

In fact Buildozer does not always apply android.api param change (https://github.com/Android-for-Python/Android-for-Python-Users#changing-buildozerspec).

You can invoke

```
buildozer appclean
```

before buildung, but I can't recommend it. It will remove whole .buildozer folder from your project, and whole long running download and compile process have to be repeated.

Instead of invoking appclean you can also update it manually.

Just edit following file:

```
your_project_folder\.buildozer\android\platform\build-xxxxxxxxx\dists\yyyyyyyyy\project.properties
```

where:

```
xxxxxxxxx it's vaule from android.arch or android.archs of buildozer.spec file
yyyyyyyyy it's value from package.name of buildozer.spec file
```

in your case:

```
package.name = testbattapp
android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a
```

so you should find this file here:

```
your_project_folder\.buildozer\android\platform\build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a\dists\testbattapp\project.properties
```

Modify following line according to your android.api param of buildozer.spec, for example:

from

```
target=android-27
```

to

```
target=android-33
```

Build apk again:

```
buildozer -v android release
```

That'a all.

During build process this value will be injected into:

```
your_project_folder\.buildozer\android\platform\build-xxxxxxxxx\dists\yyyyyyyyy\AndroidManifest.xml
```

as targetSdkVersion param in line:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="33" />
```

Comment: Thank you for feedback. I can't currently test the behaviour, because on new PC, it works as expected. If I run into the same issues again, I will make sure to test it. I figured it might be a variable not getting changed somewhere, but I didn't find where.